# Why do cumulative returns have a bimodal distribution?

Tags: returns, probability, distribution, log-returns

**Regular returns** (log-differenced prices) have statistical distributions that are bell-shaped and **unimodal** (one mode/peak) despite being non-normal and fat-tailed.

**Cumulative returns**, on the other hand, computed from regular returns as $[\prod (1+r)] -1$, are **bi-modal** (with two modes/peaks). Is there a reason for cumulative return distributions having this shape?

And in spite of cumulative returns being **non-stationary** unlike regular returns, are they used in any well-known financial models at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depending on the time period and asset considered, it comes from **different market regimes**.

e.g. if you consider a long enough period, you will clearly have distinct bull and a bear markets with crisis and changes in investors behaviors, with very different returns, there is an interesting article [there](https://klementoninvesting.substack.com/p/the-distribution-of-stock-market).

all in all if you consider just 1 regime, would expect the returns to be monomodal.

Comment: if this is the reason, then wouldn't more than two market regimes be possible (tri-, quad- modal cumulative return distributions)? if I currently only see two modes, would elongating the historical dataset another two decades surely cause more modes to appear?

Comment: yes the longer the time period the more modes, in the article linked, the time series spans over a hundred years

Comment: in spite of cumulative returns being non-stationary unlike regular returns, are they used in any well-known financial models at all? If cumulative returns appear in market regime models, is that all they're good for?